# I need MongoDB to wait for a pre-remove hook before doing other actions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to working with MongoDB (or any other database for that matter), and I have a bug in my expense manager web app.

I have some collections (**not** MongoDB collections, this is just how I call them on the website) that the user can remove. After a collection is removed from the database (and all the references to that collection), I'm fetching all the other collections.

The problem is that the server is already fetching the collections, before the collection that is supposed to be removed gets removed.

This is what's showing up in my terminal when I try to remove an collection:

```
Mongoose: collections.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b3f5dc890a1702e96a8f59a") }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: collections.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b3f5dc890a1702e96a8f59a") }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b321af4b654523b93164187") }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: collections.find({ user: ObjectId("5b321af4b654523b93164187") }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: expenses.remove({ _collection: ObjectId("5b3f5dc890a1702e96a8f59a") }, {})
Mongoose: users.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5b321af4b654523b93164187") }, { '$pullAll': { collections: [ ObjectId("5b3f5dc890a1702e96a8f59a") ] }, '$inc': { __v: 1 } })
Mongoose: collections.remove({ _id: ObjectId("5b3f5dc890a1702e96a8f59a") }, {})
```

I have tried to research how to wait for the hook to finish, but couldn't find anything. I don't even know if that's the right thing to do in my case, so I figured I should ask here.

This is my hook:

```
collectionSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
  try {
    let user = await User.findById(this.user);
    user.collections.remove(this.id);

    this.model('Expense').remove({ _collection: this.id }, next);

    await user.save();

    return next();
  } catch(err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about mongoose, but 20 seconds of googling revealed that [pre-hooks come in two varieties: serial and parallel](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). I guess yours is the latter? Would it be enough to implement it in the serial manner?

Comment: That's why I'm confused. My hook is not parallel. Something I should have probably mentioned is that it is using an async function. I've edited the question.

Comment: Does `user.collections` auto-load the collections? I wouldn't be surprised. Why don't you simply delete the collection directly? `Collection.remove({_id: this.id, user_id: this.user})` or however it's done in mongoose.

Comment: On the same note, I don't see how you need to save or even load user here. You don't use it.

Comment: I want to remove the reference from the user. That's why I need the hook in the first place. I need that reference to know which user has which collection.

Comment: I'll be damned, this IS the idiomatic way in mongoose. Alright, I'll withdraw from the discussion, because I'm evidently out of my element here. Good luck with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove(...)` promises aren't properly chained inside `async` function. Another problem is that `async` function returns a promise, and `next` is redundant with promises, at least in Mongoose 5.

It should be something like:

```
collectionSchema.pre('remove', async function() {
    let user = await User.findById(this.user);
    await user.collections.remove(this.id);    
    await this.model('Expense').remove({ _collection: this.id });
    await user.save();
});
```

Comment: I've changed my code as you said, but I'm still getting the same thing in the terminal, and the functions still run in the same order.

Comment: Besides promise chaining, still not sure what `let user = await User.findById(this.user); user.collections.remove(this.id);` is for. `this.user` is already user id, isn't it? The actual removal after pre hook is supposed to do same thing as `user.collections.remove(this.id)` does, doesn't it?

Comment: These are the only problems that I see here. Btw, you didn't specify what exactly bothers you with the order.

Comment: After the collections gets removed I still have the id to that collection in my user object:  `"collections" : [ ObjectId("5b3f782cfa72753eaa495406") ]`  What bothers me with the order is that the server is fetching the collections that I need before removing the one that should be removed, therefore displaying the same collections on the website.

Comment: I see. *the server is fetching the collections that I need* - this is not shown in the question. The problem is likely where you do this `collections.find`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem came from a function I've used to remove a collection.

Apparently I was using some voo-doo magic code that I did not understand. @estus's answer made me look over my code again and research the right way to remove a document:

```
await db.Collection.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.collection_id);
```

Thank you!